# Hang a mirror with keyhole slot

Tags: hanging, mirror

What is the best way to hang a 30" round, 35lb mirror with a keyhole slot? Diameter of keyhole is 3/8 inch.

Wall is drywall. I have located a stud, which is in the right place, but in case I don't, I'd like to hear options for non-stud approaches too.

[image]

Comment: Is there a specific type of screw to use? Do I need to worry about screws bending/shearing off?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A high-quality #12 or #14 pan-head screw (or the metric equivalent) of 2" length or more will carry that with no problem when mounted in a stud through 1/2" drywall.

For hollow-wall scenarios, such as drywall, use a substantial anchor rated for more than the weight you wish to hang, that grasps the drywall from the inside, such as a toggler (Pop Toggle pictured):

[image]